# jquery корзина изменение текста на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery

нужно сделать так чтобы в корзине при добавление заказа текст "оформить заказ" был ссылкой ведущей на страницу к примеру basket.php.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.header__menu a i').click(function() {
$('.sub-menu').toggle()
})

//тут кол-во товара
$('.add-tovar').click(function() {
var count = parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1;
$("#tovar").text(count);
if (count > 0) {
$("#kol").text("оформить заказ");
}
 });

//тут должна прибавляться цена товара
$('.add-tovar').click(function() {
  // Get total 
  var total = $('#cena').attr('data-total-price')
  // Set total converting it to number 
  total = +$(".cost", this).attr('data-price') + (+total)
  $('#cena').attr('data-total-price', total)
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Set price veiw
  $("#cena").text('$' + total);

 })


})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ, если я вас правильно понял, то добавлять не текст а тег с текстом - вместо .text() использовать .html()

```
$("#kol").html('<a href="/basket.php">оформить заказ</a>');
```

Есть вариант изменить сам тег

```
$("#kol").replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML){
  return $('<a href="/basket.php">').html(oldHTML);
});
```

*Более того, не очень понял вашу логику - в count у вас будет или NaN или число - как минимум 1. А ниже вы его проверяете на count > 0.

Comment: Логика проста,по умолчанию у меня прописанно в html  "корзина пуста" ,вот я и поставил условие если count больше чем 0 то выполняется код(надпись "корзина пуста" меняется на "оформить заказ" )// сейчас у меня надпись меняется на текст "оформить заказ" а нужно чтобы на ссылку "оформить заказ".

Comment: ну как поменять на ссылку я показал. А вот на счёт логики - у вас при клике на add-tovar:  count = parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1; Т.е. при любом раскладе у вас count  будет как минимум 1! Через одну строчку ставите проверку if (count > 0)

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручил